# How does positioning work in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I have a little problem where I have a giant recycler view (7000 items) and I have it filled up with generated cards that have college information on them and a button on the right hand side. I included a picture for you to see exactly what I mean. So here is the question: I want to fetch the name and ID when I click on the "details" button so that I can query the rest of college information from an SQLite database later but when I scroll down enough and click the button it sometimes returns information of other college instead of the one I want. The first one always works as intended though. Here is the adapter code:

```
public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<CollegeItem> collegeList;
    private List<CollegeItem> collegeListFull;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private Button details;
    private DatabaseCollege collegeDB;

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter(List<CollegeItem> collegeList, Context context) {
        this.collegeList = collegeList;
        this.context = context;
        collegeListFull = new ArrayList<>(collegeList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.college_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String id = collegeList.get(position).getId();
        final String name = collegeList.get(position).getName();
        holder.name.setText(collegeList.get(position).getName());
        holder.id.setText(collegeList.get(position).getId());
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(id + " - " + name); //This sometimes gives information of incorrect college when clicked
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collegeList.size();
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return collegeFilter;
    }

    public Filter getFilterName() {
        return collegeFilterName;
    }

    private Filter collegeFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<CollegeItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(collegeListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(CollegeItem college : collegeListFull) {
                    if(college.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(college);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            collegeList.clear();
            collegeList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private Filter collegeFilterName = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<CollegeItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(collegeListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(CollegeItem college : collegeListFull) {
                    if(college.getId().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(college);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            collegeList.clear();
            collegeList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView name, id;

        public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.college_name);
            id = v.findViewById(R.id.college_id);
            details = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_college_details);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure exactly why but it seems to be a positioning issue maybe? Because when I scroll and click the information outputed seem to change. Whats the correct way to get the information from the cards the way I want? [image]

and just in case here is the fragment java code where the recycler view sits:

```
public class CollegeFragment extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CustomRecyclerAdapter customRecyclerAdapter;
    private List<CollegeItem> collegeItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseCollege dbCollege;
    private EditText cName, cId;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college, container, false);

        dbCollege = new DatabaseCollege(getActivity());

        recyclerView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        customRecyclerAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(dbCollege.getCollegeData(), getActivity());

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customRecyclerAdapter);
        customRecyclerAdapter.setItemClickListener(this);

        cId = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.et_ipeds);
        cId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                cName.getText().clear();
                CollegeFragment.this.customRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        cName = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        cName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                cId.getText().clear();
                CollegeFragment.this.customRecyclerAdapter.getFilterName().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        return myFragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, int position) {
        String name = collegeItemList.get(position).getName();
        String id = collegeItemList.get(position).getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this problem occur after you've set filters to your list?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I thought about that, but no it isn't. It actually seems like it always gives me about 5-6 of the same names constantly. Almost as if positioning only added to the items I can currently see in recycler view. If this is the case then obviously it would take information from the first 5 items. But I have no clue how to solve it @Christilyn

Comment: How are you populating `collegeItemList`? does this list correspond with the list that you have in your adapter?

Comment: It is populated by fetching a JSON array from a collegeScorecard gov site, it is done once and then it is stored into SQLite database. I then call a method that returns an array that is populated by moving the cursor all throughout the database. That is working for sure because I tested that all the items get in there. And that array is returned by that method and the recycler view takes that in as a parameter @Christilyn
I need to fetch at least ID from the click item though to then tell the method from database what addition info to fetch for what college.

Comment: Yet somehow these 2 lines ``holder.name.setText(collegeList.get(position).getName());
        holder.id.setText(collegeList.get(position).getId());``  utilize position and populate every text view just fine

Comment: I ask because in your adapter, you're passing `dbCollege.getCollegeData()` and in your `onClick(...)` callback, your are grabbing from the `collegeItemList` and I didn't see any code that's updating `collegeItemList`. Edit: Perhaps it is your cursor that's pointing to the wrong item in the list?

Comment: I am new to working with adapters and was following a video. Is there anything I could put inside ``onClick()`` that will make it work?  @Christilyn

Comment: I notice that you store your Button inside the Adapter instead of the ViewHolder. Try moving it to the ViewHolder instead and access it through `holder.details` in your `onBindViewHolder(...)` function. Putting it inside the Adapter would just cause it to keep replacing your Button instance in your Adapter  whenever `onBindViewHolder` is called. Hence, it's giving you the wrong details.

Comment: There are also few corrections I would suggest in terms of integrating `onClick` callback in your list items. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adapter**

```
public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<CollegeItem> collegeList;
    private List<CollegeItem> collegeListFull;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseCollege collegeDB;

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter(List<CollegeItem> collegeList, Context context) {
        this.collegeList = collegeList;
        this.context = context;
        collegeListFull = new ArrayList<>(collegeList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.college_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String id = collegeList.get(position).getId();
        final String name = collegeList.get(position).getName();
        holder.name.setText(collegeList.get(position).getName());
        holder.id.setText(collegeList.get(position).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collegeList.size();
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return collegeFilter;
    }

    public Filter getFilterName() {
        return collegeFilterName;
    }

    private Filter collegeFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<CollegeItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(collegeListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(CollegeItem college : collegeListFull) {
                    if(college.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(college);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            collegeList.clear();
            collegeList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private Filter collegeFilterName = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<CollegeItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(collegeListFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for(CollegeItem college : collegeListFull) {
                    if(college.getId().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(college);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            collegeList.clear();
            collegeList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView name, id;
        Button details; // Button should be here

        public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.college_name);
            id = v.findViewById(R.id.college_id);
            details = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_college_details);

            details.setOnClickListener(this); // set click listener here instead
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you're utilizing the ItemClickListener callback that you implemented in your fragment instead of creating new instances of click listener for your details button. In this case, your listener for all items is your Fragment that implements `ItemClickListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot and god bless your soul I thought I was gonna rip my hair out

Comment: @Coda759 No problem! Glad it helped :D